# Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: typescript

I created my custom hook in react using TypeScript, but I'm getting the below error, and I don't have any Idea about this:

```
const getMode: (mode: any) => any
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
DarkModeStatus.tsx(2, 20): An argument for 'mode' was not provided.
```

The method(func) I'm using here is not getting any parameter, when I invoke the `getMode()` I'm getting the above message.

This my custom hook Code:

```
export const useDarkModeStatus = () => {
  const setMode = (mode): void => {
    console.log(mode, " setMode")
    typeof window !== "undefined" &&
      window.localStorage.setItem("theme", JSON.stringify(mode))
  }

  const getMode = () =>
    typeof window !== "undefined" &&
    JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("theme"))
  return [getMode, setMode]
}
```

There I've invoked my function:

```
import { useDarkModeStatus } from "../components/DarkModeStatus/DarkModeStatus"
 const [getMode] = useDarkModeStatus()
 useEffect(() => {
    const value = getMode()
    dispatch({ type: "INITIAL_MODE", value })
  }, [])
```

When I pass an argument to `getMode('yes')` the error is solved even I'm not receiving any parameter, thanks!

Comment: `return [getMode, setMode] as const`. Otherwise it inferres the type more generically than you expect. Alternatively declare the returned type explicitly. Another example: `const foo = [1, 'foo'];` - what type do you think this variable is? Then compare it with `as const`.

Comment: @zerkms so because it's an array, it makes both the same type? I guess it make sense even if it's quite weird here. I suppose the two can also be exported separately which would also fix the problem.

Comment: @VLAZ it tries to find the most generic type that fits all members. It's the most reasonable scenario for the compiler: it makes no assumptions at all.

Comment: @zerkms yes, thanks. That does make sense, true. And it wouldn't generalise to `Function`, since it's too wide, therefore it goes to `(mode: any) => any`, I suppose.

Comment: @zerkms thanks It solved the problem,  I would like you to write the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler tries to infer the type to be not too wide, and not to narrow to fit all the members.

With the details you provided (no at all) the inferred type for the returned result would be:

```
(() => any | (any) => void)[]
```

Given that, the first item of the value returned by this function is `() => any | (any) => void`. Which you cannot invoke without arguments.

To fix it you must either declare the returned type of the `useDarkModeStatus` explicitly, or put `as const`:

```
return [getMode, setMode] as const;
```

That way TS uses the most specific type possible: a tuple of 2 elements with every item having as specific type as possible.