# Cannot use JS react hook in Typescript component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

we are migrating our codebase from JS to Typescript.

Currently, I have a simple hook in

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert from "@mui/material/Alert";


export const useErrorDialog = () => {
    const [errorText, setErrorText] = useState(null)

    const renderErrorToast = () => {
        return (
            <Snackbar
                open={errorText !== null}
                onClose={() => setErrorText(null)}
            >
                <MuiAlert 
                    elevation={6} 
                    variant="filled"
                    severity={"error"}
                >
                    {errorText}
                </MuiAlert>
            </Snackbar>
        )
    }

    return [renderErrorToast, setErrorText]
}
```

and I want to use it in a new Typescript component

```
function Instructions() {

    const [renderErrorToast, setErrorText] = useErrorDialog()

    return (
         {renderErrorToast()}
    )
}
```

However, this leaves me with the following error:

```
TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
index.d.ts(860, 25): An argument for 'value' was not provided.
```

Could someone help me with fixing this please?

Comment: did you import react in the file where `Instructions` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly declare the returned type or put as const.

```js
return [renderErrorToast, setErrorText] as const
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965581/expected-1-arguments-but-got-0) for more details.